# Loading local JSON file error : Cross origin requests on chrome for AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, http

I am currently trying to load in a JSON file which is being uploaded from a local directory via file upload input.

This is how I am doing it:

```
var path= document.getElementById('path').value;

path = "data/" + path.match(/[^\\/]*$/)[0];

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: path
})
.then(function(success) {
    console.log(success);

}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

This works completely fine on firefox and it loads the data but I am getting this error on Chrome.

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

The URL looks like this:

```
file:///C:/Users/User%200.2/Desktop/docs/1.0/prjs/data/data.json
```

Comment: because `file:///` isn't `http://` or `https://` etc ... there is a command line argument you can add to chrome to make it behave like firefox, though, if you're a serious developer, you'll never use `file:///`

Comment: @JaromandaX So I would need to alter chrome to make it behave like firefox for it to work?

Comment: no, not alter, run chrome with a specific command line argument

Comment: @JaromandaX An alternative would be to upload the file onto a web server and access it this way?

Comment: clearly yes, because that would be http or https - or don't use crhome

Comment: @JaromandaX What would be the simplest way of accomplishing this? I'm currently looking into it but i'm not sure where I should be looking.

Comment: simplest: don't use chrome

Comment: the simpliest way is to add a cors-allow extension chrome for just to test it (not recommended for further use)